# How do I work around instaniation inside a virtual method?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a variadic class template that has a virtual function. This function uses a method from one of `Ts...`.

I want the `bar()` function to only be instantiated if `Ts...` has the `baz()`. Currently the compiler instantiates the function and reports an error that `x` has no function `baz()`. Since virtual functions cannot be templates I can't SFINAE this out.

```
template <class... Ts>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr auto I = 2;

    virtual void bar()
    {
        auto x = std::get<I>(std::make_tuple(Ts::create()...));
        x.baz();
    }
};
```

What is a way to get around this? I know I can specialize by passing off the work to a helper class from which `Foo` derives, storing the types in a tuple specializing based on the condition if `Ts...` has `baz()`, but I don't want to introduce another level of indirection. Is there some other alternative?

Update: [Here's an example program.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/337715a86a9415c2)

Comment: Who is `I`? Can you post a complete example please?

Comment: @KerrekSB http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/337715a86a9415c2

Comment: Leaving my answer there, I don't know how inheritance could be avoided. However, I'm not sure where you'd need another level of indirection (is `baz` actually supposed to have arguments?). Perhaps a bigger picture would help out.

Comment: I can think of something that just uses specializations, but that requires making `Foo` take a `tuple` (or similar) instead of a pack directly.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d1279763fbbda40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall invoke the classic "has member" trick (forgive me, I forgot where I saw it first).

I've convinced VS2013 that this is OK:

```
template<typename T>
struct HazBaz
{
    struct YesSir{char y[2];};
    struct NoSir{char y;};

    template<typename A>
    static auto Frob(A &&a) ->
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<decltype(a.baz()), decltype(a.baz())>::value,
            YesSir
        >::type;

    static NoSir Frob(...);

    static const bool value =
        sizeof(Frob(declval<T>())) == sizeof(YesSir);
};

template<typename T0, typename ...TN>
struct AllHazBaz
{
    static const bool value =
        HazBaz<T0>::value &&
        AllHazBaz<TN...>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct AllHazBaz<T>
{
    static const bool value = HazBaz<T>::value;
};

template<bool implementBar, typename ...Ts>
struct FooBase
{
    // Assuming that we do
    virtual void bar()
    {
        // Do the things here
    }
};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct FooBase<false, Ts...>
{
    // Look ma, no bar!
};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct Foo : FooBase<AllHazBaz<Ts...>::value, Ts...>
{
};
```

EDIT: Derp. Just read through the question again. Honestly, I don't know how that would be possible without inheritance.

Comment: Your example looks great! I'm fine with inheritance, I just wanted to see if there was another way.

Comment: `std::is_same<decltype(a.baz()), decltype(a.baz())>` looks weird to me. Are you sure you want to check the same `decltype` in both parameters? Perhaps `std::is_member_function_pointer()` should be used instead of `std::is_same`?

Comment: Its a SFINAE thing. It lets me put a `bool` in an `enable_if` without causing VS to explode. Note that this also works if `baz` is a static member.

Comment: Does VS explode on `std::is_member_function_pointer`? `std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&A::baz)>::value, YesSir>`. I never use SFINAE myself, and have a hard time wrapping my head around its use.

Comment: @defube Instead of the weird `is_same` invocation, couldn't you just define `template <typename> struct always_true : std::true_type {};`?

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, I could, but that would be require _even more_ typing. Though, yes, that would work. The expression just needs to trigger SFINAE (still freaking compiler dependent) without making an error. VS is just _really_ picky about what works, and conditionals that require _some_ evaluation seem to work 90% of the time.

Comment: @defube Compiler issues aside, if it's me I would prefer something that expresses the semantics of what I want as opposed to using `std::is_same` for something other than what it expresses. (Of course I understand that this answer is only intended to convey the technique, so this comment is more directed at future readers than at you, I suppose.)

Comment: @cdhowie I'd prefer actual static conditionals driven by template parameters (like an "if" following a signature). SFINAE inconsistencies drive me nuts!